# Jenkins generate new parameters based on another parameter value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a choice parameter called 'Data Center' which has two values DC01 and DC02. If user chooses DC01 I want few other build parameters to show up, if he chooses DC02 I want other parameters to show up. Is there any way to do it?

If user chooses DC01, I want two more fields such as 'hostname' and 'IP address' which are just text fields.

I have tried using Active Choice Plugin, but I don't think we can generate text field parameters using that.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

We can generate text field parameters using Active Choices Plugin.

We will use two types of parameters here: `Active Choices Parameter` and `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter`

**Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter**

In Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter, there are wide variety of rendering options available, of which one is `Formatted HTML` i.e. in the return string you can pass the html tags.

So, making use of the above two parameters, here is the pipeline code that will help in your case:

> **Note: After saving the below pipeline code, first Click on `Build Now`. After the build got success, then refresh the page. You will be able to see the option `Build with Parameters`. You can also see in the Job Configuration page, all the fields of `This build is parameterized` gets populated automatically once you build the job after saving the pipeline.**

```yaml
properties([
                            parameters([
                                [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
                                    description: 'Select the Application Service from the Dropdown List', 
                                    filterLength: 1, 
                                    filterable: false, 
                                    name: 'data_center', 
                                    script: [
                                        $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: 
                                                "return['Could not get the services list']"
                                        ], 
                                        script: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: 
                                                "return['DC01', 'DC02', 'DC03']"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                                    description: 'enter job params',
                                    name: 'hostname', 
                                    referencedParameters: 'data_center', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                if (data_center.contains('DC01')){
                                                    return """<textarea name=\"value\" rows=\"5\" class=\"setting-input   \"></textarea>"""

                                                } else 
                                                if (data_center.contains('DC02')){
                                                    return """<textarea name=\"value\" rows=\"5\" class=\"setting-input   \"></textarea>"""

                                                }
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ],
                                omitValueField: true
                                ],
                                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                                    description: 'enter job params',
                                    name: 'ipaddress', 
                                    referencedParameters: 'data_center', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                if (data_center.contains('DC01')){
                                                    return """<textarea name=\"value\" rows=\"5\" class=\"setting-input   \"></textarea>"""

                                                } else 
                                                if (data_center.contains('DC02')){
                                                    return """<textarea name=\"value\" rows=\"5\" class=\"setting-input   \"></textarea>"""

                                                }
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ],
                                omitValueField: true
                                ],
                                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                                    description: 'enter job params',
                                    name: 'port_number', 
                                    referencedParameters: 'data_center', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                if (data_center.contains('DC02')){
                                                    return """<textarea name=\"value\" rows=\"5\" class=\"setting-input   \"></textarea>"""

                                                }
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ],
                                omitValueField: true
                                ]                               
                            ])
                        ])
pipeline {
    environment {
         vari = ""
  }
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{

          echo "${params.data_center}"
          echo '\n'
          echo "${params.hostname}"
          echo "${params.ipaddress}"
          echo "${params.port_number}"
          
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]

Output when data center `DC01` is selected,

[image]

[image]

Output when data center `DC02` is selected,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I don't want the fields to show up be default. I want them to show up conditionally. Is that something which we can achieve?