# Showing new parameter after choosing one

Tags: jenkins, plugins

Is there a way to set a Jenkins Job to display a param (before running) only after choosing one?
Meaning, if a user chooses some checkbox, only then, a new param for choosing is being displayed

for example: I want to have a checkbox called runAuto - when user mark it, only then a new field (another checkbox) will appear, called  skipCommon

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked thru [Build Parameters plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search/?labels=parameter)?

Active Choices, Dynamic Choice, Extended Choice, Extensible Choice, Multi-Select parameter all work differently along those lines.

Comment: Yes I did, none seems to fit the need I described above, are you familiar with one specific that can answer it?

Comment: I don't quite get your expectation, but I would think [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) Reactive supports "dynamic options" and "cascade updates"

Comment: I already checked it, I wil try to explain myself better in the Q.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Active Choices Parameter` and `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter`

Hope this post might help you:

[Jenkins generate new parameters based on another parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395488/jenkins-generate-new-parameters-based-on-another-parameter-value/64398244#64398244)

Comment: Yeah, the same has been covered in the link I have shared. Have you gone through it ?

Comment: Yes I did, but it seems that it not answering my Q, you can see alsoe in the comment there, he also want the second choice to be invisible, and to show it only if the user choose the first option