# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: How to call functions from "Active choices reactive reference parameter's Groovy script"?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am trying to build a pipeline that can,

- take multiple inputs from a users using build parameters.
- Based on the user's first input(a drop-down), the pipeline would update the *remaining input choices*.
- I want to update the *remaining input choices* based on output of a function.

My approach:

- I am updating *remaining input choices* using "Active choice reactive reference parameter(ACRRF)" groovy script. The groovy script allows users to set a value based on the reference parameter.

Problem:

- The ACRRF's groovy script does not parse the function i.e the parameters value can not be updated using the output of a certain function.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZlpu.png)

Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a text area based on the `Active Choices Parameter`, you have to do like this:

Sample code:

```
if (data_center.contains('DC01')){
   return """<textarea name="value" rows="5" class="setting-input">
             </textarea>"""

          } else

if (data_center.contains('DC02')){
         return """<textarea name="value" rows="5" class="setting-input">
                     </textarea>"""
                }
```

You need to select `Choice Type` as `Formatted HTML`

For more details, please refer this post:

[Jenkins generate new parameters based on another parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395488/jenkins-generate-new-parameters-based-on-another-parameter-value/64398244#64398244)